# Receiving null value in POST param

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I receive a null value always in web api rest post request to a controller

In my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
{

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(customer); #CustomerApp.Models.Customer
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(customer.FirstName); #null

}
```

Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Request:

```
POST: http://localhost:21894/api/customer/postcustomer

Content-Type: application/json

body: {FirstName: "xxxx", LastName: 'yyyy'}
```

I tried the following solutions but nothing works out

https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/c-supporting-textplain-in-an-mvc-4-rc-web-api-application/

[How to get POST data in WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832784/how-to-get-post-data-in-webapi)

Can anybody guide me with help or the correct link

**Answer:**
Made a curl request instead of dealing with postman as like this gave me the solution

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"FirstName":"Jefferson","LastName":"sampaul"}' http://localhost
:21894/api/customer/postcustomer
```

Comment: Try to send just "xxxx" instead of {FirstName: "xxxx", LastName: 'yyyy'}

Comment: I am getting xxxx now

Comment: your problem is that when you send {FirstName: "xxxx", LastName: 'yyyy'} you send object with fields but getting just string

Comment: How are you making the request? Are you sure the payload is what you expect it to be? For example in JS you might need to use something like JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean to have a `Customer` object as input like below instead of `string`

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
 {
```

Well make this below change and try reposting the request. It should work

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer)
 {
   return OK(customer.FirstName);
 }
```

Request:

```
POST: http://localhost:21894/api/customer/postcustomer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"Id":101,"FirstName":"xxxx","LastName":'yyyy'}
```

Comment: ah you beat me to it

Comment: but System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(customer.FirstName); does not print any value

Comment: @Jefferson, how you are making the API request? edit your question and include that information

Comment: Ok is not accepted, throws error. I am not able to print FirstName

Comment: The json parameter had to be sent with a string. This cleared my problem

Comment: @Jefferson post your findings

Answer (score 3):

set your entity to be a customer not a string

```
[HttpPost]
public Customer PostCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(customer);
    return customer;
}
```

Make sure you have [HttpPost] attribute on your method also no need for the [FromBody]

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(customer.FirstName); does not print any value

Comment: @Jefferson what version of Web-Api are you using? Are you posting from AJax or a form?

Comment: Just so you know the post you're following is to support plain/text not JSON if you're just trying to get you customer model binded, You should probably follow a different tutorial. I will post some trouble shooting update in a second

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(customer);
prints CustomerApp.Models.Customer

Comment: It should because it will always be that type you should just try printing the first name

Comment: I am not getting any o/p

Comment: Do you have HttpPost attribute above your method?

Comment: I noticed that you are following a post to support plain/text this could be causing issues in your configuration.  Start a new project with only the customer and controller.

Comment: http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/rest-based-crud-operations-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx                                 this is  the tutorial I followed

Comment: @Jefferson, if you followed that tutorial you should have everything there step by step, why aren't you returning a customer.  Try like how I have it above now

Comment: I think there is a problem with retrieveing the data. There is something to do with json parse

Comment: The json parameter had to be sent with a string. This cleared the problem.