# How to bind model in web api (like happen in mvc)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My Html code is something like this.

```
<input type="text" name="Id" value="123"/>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="XYZ"/>
<input type="text" name="Abc.Address" value="ABC,XYZ 700567"/>
<input type="text" name="Abc.Mobile" value="6958743216"/>
```

Classes:-

```
class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Abc Abc { get; set; }
}

class Abc
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Mobile{ get; set; }
}
```

Through upper input When I am calling MVC controller the then binding happen.
means for following method

```
public ActionResult Post(A x)
```

value in x is

```
x.Id="123"
x.Name="XYZ"
x.Abc.Address="ABC,XYZ 700567"
x.Abc.Mobile="6958743216"
```

but when I tried same things in web api it is giving me 415(Unsupported media type). means for following method

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(A x)
```

instead of binding it is giving 415 status code saying Unsupported Media Type.
I know it is stupid to ask but why this happen? and if I want to do same binding as happen in mvc how can I achieve that?(I don't want to do something like this
--> `public IHttpActionResult Post([SomeBinder]A x)`)

Is there way to achieve this or Not?

Comment: How are you posting the data?

Comment: _How are you posting the data? _ don't get it. If you mean how I send this data then ans is through form-submit

Comment: Web API should not be used directly against HTML forms, that's what MVC is for

Comment: So if I want to make api, then I how will I do it? Is there any work around?

Comment: are you calling this action method from fiddler or postman?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 415 Unsupported Media Type: POST not reaching REST if JSON, but it does if XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get POST data in WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832784/how-to-get-post-data-in-webapi)

Comment: @Crowcoder the answer given in link not solving problem at all(still giving same error).

Comment: show how you make the request in PostMan then, if that's what's giving you the 415 error.

Comment: from postman in body I select form-data and then pass name as key from input tag above and value as value and then send in response it is giving 415.

Comment: Show exactly (screenshot maybe) if you can. A description of something doesn't mean it was done correctly. Also, test if the API method works if you use JSON instead.

Comment: It is working for json

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the `Content-Type` of the request.

Your WebAPI endpoint is expecting your post request to have the `Content-Type` `application/json`. Once you add that it will be accepted.

However if you want to post an HTML form to a controller you shouldn't use WebAPI. If you have to then you can serialize the form and submit the form using javascript